# How can I pack my images into the App and work with them?

Tags: android, image

I have written a imageprocessing app with javacv. I have some samples which are there to find some objects on a taken picture. The problem is that my program just gets nullpointerexception.

```
static String objectFilename = "assets/sblinksoben.png";

object = cvLoadImage(objectFilename,
                CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

The first one is the path and the last one is how I load the image. Evertime when I check it with my debugger it only stands object = null.

So my guess is that the images are not getting packed into the .apk and the program will not find anything.

Does someone have solution for it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> So my guess is that the images are not getting packed into the .apk

Yes, they are. However, they are not files. They are entries in the ZIP archive that is the APK file. You can get an `InputStream` on them via `getAssets().open()`. However, if "javacv" cannot work with `InputStreams`, you will either need to copy the file yourself to internal storage first, or you will need to find a more flexible library.